# Babel: The CLI has been moved into the package `babel-cli`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I was working on a JS file at work where I had babel installed, running `babel file.js | node`
I sent the file home to work in the evening, installed babel at home and I got the following error when I run the above command:

```
The CLI has been moved into the package 'babel-cli'
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance :)

If I install the CLI - the following code fails to compile:

```
function sumArrayIndex(array, i, separator) {
  return array
    .map(x => x.split(separator)
      .map(c => { return parseInt(c) })
    )
    .map(x => { return x[i]; })
    .reduce((x, y) => { return x += y }, 0);
}

function minToSec(m) {
  return m * 60
}

function secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(s) {
  var min = s / 60;
  var sec = s % 60;

  minutes += Math.floor(min);
  seconds += sec;
}

function outputTime() {
  return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}
```

Comment: Babel 6 was released recently. It introduced a few breaking changes. Have you tried installing the package `babel-cli`?

Comment: I did, yes, but then I get syntax errors on valid es6

Comment: Out of interest what did Babel 6 fail to compile?

Comment: I will add the code above.

Comment: What isn't clear about this message?

Comment: does babel cli mean you don't need webpack?

Comment: This question is a good one, the babel 6 official upgrade guide is not out yet for this and I'm seeing some buggy stuff.  From reading https://medium.com/@malyw/how-to-update-babel-5-x-6-x-d828c230ec53, it appears that the 'babel' module should not be used in 6.0, however it is still in babels packages directory and still getting published `6.1.18` being the latest https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages. When I have `babel`, `babel-cli`, and `babel-core` installed alongside each other, I get this same error when running npm scripts via babel-node.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Babel version 6](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/) split the project into several modules. As the message indicates the CLI has moved to `babel-cli`.

I suggest you use the same version that you use at work (which is probably v5):

```
npm install -g babel@5
```

However, if you would rather use the latest version:

```
npm install -g babel-cli
```

Comment: Boom! Thank you very much, used v5 :)

Comment: The babel people warn against the use of babel-cli globally: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: I think it is a good idea to install all dependencies locally, but it is sometimes useful to have a `babel-node` on `$PATH` for trying things out.